Implementation of Angular Metric for Shape Similarity (AMSS) with Python
Is there any existing optimized Python implementation of Angular Metric for Shape Similarity (AMSS)?
Otherwise, could I approximate it by considering the derivative DTW and using cosine similarity instead of euclidean distance?
UPDATE
I tried to implement it using tslearn package as below:
    import numpy as np
    from tslearn.metrics import dtw_path_from_metric
    from scipy.spatial import distance

    def amss(x,y):
        return dtw_path_from_metric(np.gradient(x),np.gradient(y), metric=distance.cosine)[1]

Still I'm not sure if it is a good approximate of AMSS.

There is no as such python implementation of AMSS available online. So, you can directly email the original authors of the paper on AMSS. Otherwise, yes you can use DDTW to approximate as demonstrated by many published papers.
The closest python implementation that might help you is this open source python implementation of Dynamic Time Warping (DTW) https://github.com/aras-y/DTW_with_missing_values
Hope it helps and Good Luck!

Thanks @Naveed ! I tried to implement it using dtw_path_from_metric function from tslearn package (as I'm already using it). I've just added the code above. Still I'm not sure if it is a good approximation of AMSS.

Regarding " I'm not sure if it is a good approximation of AMSS.", you can check the difference/performance metrics. can you upvote if you find my answer somewhat helpful, thanks
